# Google Client API: Oauth2 API failing : Request timeout Curl Error 28,

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am creating Google Login option for my web application. I am using CodeIgniter.
I had integrated the Google Client API, and code was working well, i was able to do google login.

Suddenly from last 2 days, i started getting following error.

-----Error
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException

Message: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
....

-----/Error

Mainly i see this time out is happening for the function
Function: fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode

previous day i somehow restarted the PC and tried disabling the firewall in my router and antivirus, then it started working, login was again working normally. (Since previous day i had installed new router).

But next day i see same error again, and i am not able to do anything now. I wanted to understand root cause for this. and How do it really solve this issue?

My Platform: CodeIgniter
Server: XAMPP

Code is standard Google Client API access.

Please help me if anybody knows how to solve this issue?

I have also tried changing DNS to google and OpenDNS both in router and also later in windows adapter settings also. But still no luck on this.

-Games

Comment: Facing same problem with Google Cloud Vision API in my mobile application project. It was working perfectly till 5 days before. Now its sending response as timedout exception. If I user VPN in mobile then api working perfectly. Anyone know what is the problem and how to solve this?